# Opencart images align vertically instead of horizontal

Tags: html, css, opencart

I have a opencart website that I need to fix the extension. My site is

http://qubuu.com

The extension work like this: When customer add an item to cart and the system popup a success message, it will also show 4 related product below the message. When i try to add to cart, the image did show up but only 1, I believe the other 3 are below but its vertical and the position is set to 'fixed', so it wouldn't show up.

What I wanna know is, how can we make those 4 images align horizontally and resize to fit into the box? Any Idea?

Comment: show css for images..

Comment: add `float:left;` or `display:inline-block;` to `img`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, visit the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to ask a good question. You'll find out that a good question requesting debugging help should always contain a code to use for problem reproduction or direct solution. Posting a link to your site is not a good idea as it could be considered as SPAM (unwanted advertisement). In this case you should post (**here in the question**) the HTML and CSS code responsible for the issue you are asking about.

Comment: The problem is I can't really locate where that image css is, any idea? @reenleedr